# How to optimise the sql query which runs on millions of records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, query-optimization

I have a sql table with following columns:
id,name,employee_number,age,class

I need to update the employee_number which is of the form:
`1234 56XX XXXX 7890`

to the new value:
`XXXX XXXX XXXX 7890`

I have created the following query to do the task and written a script to execute it in loop:

```
UPDATE tablename 
    SET employee_number = concat('XXXX XXXX XXXX ',right(card_number,4)) 
where employee_number regexp '^[0-9]{4}' 
order by id asc 
limit ?";
```

The '?' is being replaced by the user argument which I have given as 50 000 records. I have 200 million records. The script is still running from 3 days and it has updated only 70 million records. I have put a sleep of 5 seconds after each update to maintain cpu usage at a nominal level.

My questions are:

1. Is the query correct to do the required task?
2. Why is it taking this much time? is it due to the regexp?
3. Is there a better way? Is it possible to do small changes to the query so that it runs quickly on all the records. quickly meaning at least a day or two maybe?

Please suggest a better and optimised way.

Comment: Why do you `ORDER BY` when updating? Do you have correct indices set up? What explain plan do you get? What datatype is `employee_number` – if it is a number, why not check `>9999`? 200 millions isn't all that much and shouldn't run for days, only minutes (or hours; but definitely not days)

Comment: I have put order by as to avoid any random updates to the record and have updates in ascending order. index is on id in the table. data type of employee_number is varchar(50) . I have mentioned its type so its not a number. Any idea why is it taking a lot of time? Is it due to the regex matching ?

Comment: Yes. Looks like regexp is leading to full scan on table. You can verify it by checking execution plan.

Comment: The whole order by / limit business seems like a waste of time to me.  You're doing that regular expression check on the whole table regardless of this.  And by trying to break this into chunks and running the query several times over, you're just running the same table scan over and over.  Forget the order by and limit, and just do the query once.

Comment: Is there a way to optimise. I have kept regex to keep it as a check and stop the execution once it doesn't find such pattern. How to check execution plan ?

Comment: And if yo want to do it in batches get rid of `order by` and change `where` to `where employee_number < 'X'`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if I remove the order by and limit. It will eat up complete cpu usage as it will be executing on millions of records at once. In addition to that, I will not have any method to stop the loop of execution. Please suggest how can I remove those and still maintain these required things.

Comment: Well, if the purpose of the regexp is to stop rows from being updated more than once, you could do something more efficient like `where length(employee_number) = 4`

Comment: Looking at that query I'm struggling to imagine how I could possibly make it go any slower than you have already done. Since you've given us hardly any details about the table structure, nothing about the data distribution and no explain plans, this is impossible to answer,

Comment: Length will be same before and after update as I am masking the initial digits by 'X'.
@talex employee_number is a varchar . How can I write it as < 'X'

Comment: I don't believe this will use any more CPU without the order by and limit than it does now.

Comment: @symcbean What more info do you require. Informed about the indexes in table, columns, value datatypes. what else my friend ?

Comment: @ROHITKUMARDUBEY you can compare varchars. Number go before letter in all charsets I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that `REGEXP` cannot use an index. It will require a table-scan of all 200 million rows during every update. This is probably why it is taking so long. You have done 1400 big table-scans in 3 days. :-(

I would do it this way:

```
UPDATE tablename 
  SET employee_number = CONCAT('XXXX XXXX XXXX ', RIGHT(card_number, 4)) 
WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?
  AND employee_number REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}'
```

Selecting a range of rows by primary key is pretty efficient. It doesn't scan the whole table. It only examines the rows that match the range.

The first value to use for `? AND ?` starts with the minimum id value, which may be 1, or it might be higher in your table. The second value is equal to the first value plus the batch size. I would choose a smaller batch size, even a small batch like 1000.

Once the batch finishes, add 1000 (or whatever you choose as the batch size) to the two parameter numbers, and run it again. Each batch should run faster, because it doesn't have to do a table-scan.

It's okay if there are gaps in the `id` values. For example, suppose some rows between 11250 and 11350 are missing. It just means the batch of 1000 only scans 900 rows, and it will simply finish more quickly. Then you move on to the next batch.

---

I assume that `id` is the primary key, because this is a popular design. But it would be helpful when you ask a question about query optimization to include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` in your question, so we don't have to make any assumption about which column is the primary key, or the data types, indexes, or constraints in the table. It helps us to help you! :-)

Comment: Thats a clear answer to my question. Thanks a lot Bill.